# strange program output for strcpy

Tags: c

here i have a very simple program, and the output is very strange to me,

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

void func_stack();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    func_stack();
}

void func_stack() {
    int a = -1;
    char s[4];
    int b = -1;

    strcpy(s,"1234");
    printf("a+b result to %d\n",a+b);
}
```

i guess the strcpy function use '\0' override something for later int variable "b", and give a strange compute result, but after i compile it on x86 linux machine, i still got -2 as result, it is the same result as there is no strcpy happen.

anyone can explain why this happen?

Answer (score 3):

C strings are NUL-terminated. When you use `strcpy()` to copy `"1234"` to `s`, there are actually *five* bytes copied, including the NUL terminator. You are then writing beyond the bounds of the `s` array, and therefore are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

What *actually* happens when you run this will depend on your CPU architecture and your compiler (and compiler options, optimisations, etc).

Comment: i have compile it on the sparc machine, it also give -2 result,

Comment: If you want to know *exactly* what will happen on any given machine, compile it and then look at the generated assembly code. That's the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

change the array size to + 1

ex:
`"you"` so the array size is 3+1 >> char s[4];

so for your code
`"1234"` the array size is 4+1 >> char s[5];

1 last byte is used for `NULL` as end of string.

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Your `strcpy` is trying to copy 5 characters. i.e. `1234\0` into an array of 4 characters. That is why you are observing this behaviour as it is overwriting something on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg said, you are invoking undefined behavior, and thus anything can happen. Is the machine you're working on 64 bit? If so, it's possible that the variables are word aligned, and thus `s` has an extra 4 bytes of padding before the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing a=b=-1, all bits in them should be 1s.
Using a debugger or printf, you can check where the '\0' for s[4] is getting written into by checking the addresses of

```
&s[4], 
((char*)&a) and ((char*)&a)+(sizeof(int)-1),
((char*)&b) and ((char*)&b)+(sizeof(int)-1)
```

If addresses of a & b do not overlap with s[0] .. s[4], then you'll get the result -2.